# FSEvent callback function is never called

Tags: c++, macos, qt, fsevents

I am implementing folder path monitoring in my software. Due to recursive monitoring demand, I decided to use FSEvents framework rather than k_queue for Mac OS version.

I have read [File System Events API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-DontLinkElementID_11) so I implemented my wrapper class like [this example](https://gist.github.com/robertknight/3149811).

Problem is that callback function is never called.

Comment: Why is there a "`qt`" tag here? Are you running this within "`qt`"?  Have you used the Xcode debugger to see if the "`MacFSEventsWatcher::start()`" function makes it all the way through successfully?

Comment: Are you running the event loop (by calling `app.exec()` in `main`)? Qt's event loop internally spins a native event loop and that's required to receive native callbacks.

Comment: It is qt project and I already checked with debuger all functions calling and isRunnig() method.
@Kuba Ober
At first it was library project, but also i run it as independet console qt app (with main and app.exec()) and all is the same, no callback firing.